# How do i partially hydrate an object without redundant results in a one-to-one relationship with or without DQL?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to fetch basic data from my **DB** to display these into a slider, and i don't want to fetch all the data for optimisation purpose, so i've made a simple method inside my **Entity Repository** to handle this... but when i run the bellow method, i will have redundant results like **document * image**

```
public function getLastGuidesSamples()
{
    return $this->_em->createQuery("
        SELECT
            document.slug,
            document.title,
            document.description,
            image.source,
            image.alternative,
            image.width,
            image.height
        FROM AppBundle:Document document
        JOIN AppBundle:Image image
        WHERE document.type = 3
        AND document.isPublished = true
        ORDER BY document.addingDate
    ")->setMaxResults(5)->getResult();
}
```

e.g. if i have **10 documents**, and for some reasons **17 images** i will have a total of **170 results**, and if i set the maximum results to 5, all the results will be **the first document with 5 differents images** (image 1, image 2, image 3, etc... until image 17).

So how do i partially hydrate an object without redundant results in a **one-to-one relationship** with or without DQL?

Comment: How can a one to one have more than one image?

Comment: nothing special, i have removed few documents manually before, so i have orphen images.

Comment: I think you are missing thw condition for the join, e.g. WITH image.id = document.image_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `WITH` condition was missing, the following function pay the bills :

```
public function getLastGuidesSamples()
{
    return $this->_em->createQuery("
        SELECT
            document.slug,
            document.title,
            document.description,
            document.addingDate,
            document.addingAuthor,
            image.source,
            image.alternative,
            image.width,
            image.height
        FROM AppBundle:Document document
        JOIN AppBundle:Image image
        WITH image.id = document.id
        WHERE document.type = 3
        AND document.isPublished = true
        ORDER BY document.addingDate
    ")->setMaxResults(5)->getResult();
}
```